# Haskell Invert Pair

Tags: haskell

Wondering if I could get some help writing this function. I am trying to create a function that inverts each "pair" in the list.

```
module Invert where
invert :: [(a,b)] -> [(b,a)]
invert [(a,b)] = [(b,a)]
```

When I enter `invert [(3,1) (4,1) (5,1)]`... it is supposed to give me `[(1,3) (1,4) (1,5)`... But it gives me...

---

```
*Invert> [(3,1) (4,1) (5,1)]

<interactive>:2:2:
    The function `(3, 1)' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `(t0, t1)' has none
    In the expression: (3, 1) (4, 1) (5, 1)
    In the expression: [(3, 1) (4, 1) (5, 1)]
    In an equation for `it': it = [(3, 1) (4, 1) (5, 1)]
```

Comment: Forgot the commas lol...but it is still giving me "Non- exhaustive patterns in function invert"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since lists are recursive data structures, you have to process a list recursively in order to swap all its elements, or use some higher order function that does the processing for you. If you define

```
invert [(a,b)] = [(b,a)]
```

it will only convert single-element lists, all other inputs will fail with an error!

Try to think about the input `invert` gets: It's either an empty list, or a non-empty lists. In the case of a non-empty list, you can swap the first element and convert the rest recursively.

(If you don't want to invert `invert` yourself, just use

```
invert = map swap
```

where [`swap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Tuple.html#v%3aswap) is from `Data.Tuple`.)

Comment: Thanks I figured it out! I ended up using explicit recursion :)

Comment: To clarify for other people, when you write `invert [(a,b)] = [(b,a)]`, you are really writing `invert ((a,b):[]) = (b,a):[]`, which is why that function only works on lists of one element.  This is a frequent source of confusion for beginners.

Answer (score 5):

So you want to map a function over the list that's of type `(a, b) -> (b, a)`.  The function `(,)` has type `b -> a -> (b,a)`.  So if we flip it, we get `a -> b -> (b, a)`.  Now if we uncurry *that*, we get `(a, b) -> (b, a)`:

```
 invert = map (uncurry $ flip (,))
```

E.g.

```
 > map (uncurry $ flip (,)) [(1, "a"), (2, "b")]
 [("a",1),("b",2)]
```

As an aside, your patten matching doesn't match what you want. The definition

```
invert [(a,b)] = [(b,a)]
```

says *"match a list with a single tuple in it"*.  If you have a list with multiple tuples, the match will fail.  Also, as Josh Lee pointed out, you need commas between tuples in your list.

Comment: Much more concisely written as `map swap`.

Answer (score 5):

Best way to solve this: split it into smaller problems, and either find library functions that solve those, or write your own.  I always tell beginners that this is a superior exercise than trying to write a function like `invert` in just one part, because you should be learning the following three things:

1. How to split a problem into small, reusable pieces.
2. The standard library functions offered by the language.
3. How to use recursion to write small, reusable functions like the ones in the standard library.

In this case, we can split the problem into:

1. Inverting an individual tuple.
2. Applying a function to all elements of a list, and collecting the list of results.

The second one is just the common `map` function on lists, which comes with the standard library.  You could try writing your own version of it; this sort of thing is always a good exercise for a beginner:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f []     = ...
map f (x:xs) = ...
```

The first, as Petr points out, is the `swap` function from `Data.Tuple`.  But we can write our own easily:

```
swap :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
swap (a, b) = (b, a)
```

And now, of course:

```
invert :: [(a, b)] -> [(b, a)]
invert = map swap
```